# Fragments not displayed after several swipes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Context:
Implementation of an activity swiping with 3 fragments, each fragments quite "heavy" in memory use.

Symptoms:
After several swipe, right and left fragment are not displayed anymore and replaced by a black empty background. Center fragment is still displayed.

To be noticed:

- I used this same implementation below for other projects with
  fragments containing more static layouts without any problem.
- The problem seems not appear on all devices.

My implementation of the FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(final FragmentManager fm, final Context context) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(final int i) {
    switch (i) {
    case 0:
      return new FragmentA();
    case 1:
      return new FragmentB();
    default:
      return new FragmentC();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

In my activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
```

...

```
  private MyFragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter;
  private ViewPager mViewPager;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dummy);

    this.fragmentPagerAdapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter.
    this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.actMainPager);
    this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.fragmentPagerAdapter);
```

My supposition is that the fragments are destroyed to free some memory and not created anymore.

What I tried:

- Using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, as my fragments contain a lot of "heavy" data.
- I couldn't find anything related to this problem here or googling.

Has someone ever experienced this problem and have a solution for it? Do I do something wrong?

---

**Edit**

Following the stack trace, the fragment has been detached. Does someone know why? How to reatach it?

```
Exception in handleMessage: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment StatusFragment{41f9bc20} not attached to Activity
03-19 12:46:06.743: W/BaseFragment(30801):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:579)
03-19 12:46:06.743: W/BaseFragment(30801):  at com.dummy.fragment.BaseFragment.updateButtonStatus(BaseFragment.java:482)
03-19 12:46:06.743: W/BaseFragment(30801):  at com.dummy.fragment.BaseFragment$MyHandler.handleMessage(BaseFragment.java:467)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself, althought this is a **workaround**. Set `setOffscreenPageLimit` of `ViewPager` to 2 instead of 1 in order for the 2 Left and Right Fragment never to be detached:

```
this.mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.actMainPager);
this.mViewPager.setAdapter(this.fragmentPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```

This works but it does not explains why Fragments are not reattached and would not be acceptable for higher number of Fragment as it prevents memory freeing.